# Django and AuthOpenId error

Tags: django, openid

I'm trying to set up OpenID authentication in Django, using django-authopenid.

The [instructions](http://bitbucket.org/benoitc/django-authopenid/wiki/Getting_started) are pretty good, but having followed them and made all the requisite changes in settings.py and added the required templates, my whole site is now showing a 500 error, having previously worked fine. The Apache logs show:

```
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 73, in get_response
response = middleware_method(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_authopenid-1.0.1-py2.6.egg/django_authopenid/middleware.py", line 36, in process_request
request.associated_openids = [rel.openid_url for rel in rels]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 93, in _result_iter
self._fill_cache()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 660, in _fill_cache
self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 207, in iterator
for row in self.query.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 287, in results_iter
for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2345, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 19, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ProgrammingError: relation "django_authopenid_userassociation" does not exist
```

Looks like a SQL error (I'm not a django expert)?

It's possible I've put my templates in the wrong place, the instructions aren't very clear. I just added two new directories, registration and openauthid, in the main templates folder.

Bit baffled - can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you've not yet set up the required tables. Try running:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

from the project directory.

Comment: ah :) thank you! will email the project owner and ask him to add this step to the docs.